# Is dnf supported on Centos 7?

Tags: centos, dnf

`dnf` has become the *default* package manager in Centos 8 but [the December 2020 RedHat decision](https://blog.centos.org/2020/12/future-is-centos-stream/) about cutting it's support at the end of 2021 has made a lot of us stick with Centos 7, which [will get security updated until June 2024](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product).

`dnf` is *available* on Centos 7 though. And it would be good to switch to it for performance and resource usage reasons. (For example: on our Centos 7 machines `yum` can take up to 350MB of RAM when it is called by Puppet, even during runs where it's not updating or installing any packages!)

But my question is: is `dnf` **supported** on Centos 7? In other words: is the project tested on it, will it get security updates if needed, will the reported bugs be fixed?

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple arguments for the thesis that it **is not** supported:

Here's what I found:

- The [dnf GitHub project's README](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf#installing) provides info how to install it only for Fedora and states "In other RPM-based distributions you need to build all the components from their sources.".

  - ...but it in fact the `dnf` RPM package for Centos 7 **is** available in the Centos `extras` repo, but it is v. 4.0.9, from Nov 2018 ([appropriate dnf changelog entry](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/blob/master/dnf.spec#L768-L779)), while the current latest version is [4.5.2](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/releases) (from Dec 2020).
- [This dnf FAQ entry](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_faq.html#can-i-have-dnf-and-yum-installed-side-by-side) says that it *is* safe to install `dnf` next to `yum` and provides a tool for migrating the history from `yum` to `dnf` ...but the command provided did not work for me as there is no such package as `python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate` - this plugin is in the `dnf-plugins-core` package instead. But after running it with `dnf migrate` it errored with `RuntimeError: Exec failed: no such table: main.trans_cmdline`...
- The Centos wiki page about using `dnf` on Centos 7 as `yum4` - https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/ConfigManagementSIG/YUM4 - is not up to date as it is referring to Centos 7.5, released in 2018.
- On the Centos blog the latest info about this is an article from 2018 - https://blog.centos.org/2018/04/yum4-dnf-for-centos-7-updates/ and the last question there - "Is it safe to use yum4/dnf on CentOS 7?" - has been unanswered for more than 1 year (since Dec 2019)...

---

...on the other hand, there are also arguments for the thesis that it **is** supported and maybe that support is just well not documented and updated (in a typical open source project way )?

Arguments for:

- [RedHat Bugzilla **does** contain bug reports from users of `dnf` on Centos 7](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?f1=component&f2=short_desc&list_id=11636642&o1=equals&o2=substring&query_format=advanced&v1=dnf&v2=Centos) and RedHat employees did work on them.